# Factorization into Circulant Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

For any matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, is it always possible to factorize it into $AYA^T$, with $Y$ being a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)? The dimension of $A$ and $Y$ are not constrained.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be quite interesting theorem if it was possible. But I personally don't know. I only suspect that if $A$ is orthogonal it would not be possible as eigenvalues of circulant matrix are often complex and orthogonal change of basis preserves eigenvalues, so it would be hard to transform for example complex into real ones. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues

Comment: When $A$ is nonsingular, the answer is no. All rank-1 real circulant matrices are symmetric. So, when $n>1$, you cannot write a non-symmetric real rank-1 matrix $M$ as $AYA^T$. I'm not sure about singular or rectangular $A$, though.